# PHPStorm use private key to sign commit

Tags: git, phpstorm, sign

How do I sign git commit in PhPStorm?

command-line which works (the option '-S'):

```
git commit -S -m "My message"
```

But cannot find a way to achieve it using PHPStorm.

Comment: It's almost certain that this is not possible. You can change the git executable (https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/git.html) but you can't set the parameters for git commit, and the option is quite new (git 1.7.9+), which makes it less ikely to have been included.

Comment: Please vote for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110261 Also you can find a workaround there.

Comment: I tried workaroung https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110261#comment=27-1247095 - It works for me.

Comment: @artspb - If you'd like, and you cite workaround of Marijn Vriens here, I'll accept it as the solving answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best bet is the workaround suggested in the current bug filing [IDEA-110261
Support git commit -S (GPG commit sigining)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110261#comment=27-1247095).

1. In your terminal, set the project to to sign: `git config commit.gpgsign true`
2. In the config file `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` add:

   ```
   no-tty
   use-agent
   ```